# pgr_dijkstra one to many

Tags: pgrouting, dijkstra

I´m using pgr_dijkstra one to one and it´s ok, but error occour when I try one to many or many to many. I´m typing:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('select id, source ,target, cost from edge',
                           35681, 
                           ARRAY[34450,34926], 
                           FALSE);
```

The message is:

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: do not exist the funcion
>   pgr_dijkstra(unknown, integer,integer[],boolean)

May tell me where is the error?

Comment: What version of pgr_routing do you have installed?

Comment: Check specs for your version of pgrouting - there was a major changes in this function parameters - there is possibility that you don't need last one.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the pgr_bdDijkstra function. This function generates a route from one origin to several destinations.

```
--Exemple    
SELECT * FROM pgr_bdDijkstra('select id, source ,target, cost from edge',
                           35681, 
                           ARRAY[34450,34926], 
                           FALSE);
```

I hope it helped you

Comment: Ok Rogerio, thank you very much

Comment: @Marcio, it is useful when providing feedback letting other users know if the answer was helpful or not (and if not, why). Please, read https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Tks.